# D-flip flop with 2 reset: synthesis error

Tags: verilog, synthesis, register-transfer-level

I'm doing a synthesis of a digital block and I need a D-Flip-Flop with 2 asynchronous resets.  The reason is that I will drive one reset with an available clock, and I will use the second one to reset all the registers of my digital block.  I prepared the following code:

```
module dff_2rst(q,qn,clk,d, rst,clear);
    input  clk,d, rst, clear ;
    output q,qn;
    reg q,qn;

    always @(posedge clk or posedge rst or posedge clear)    //asynchronous reset    
    begin 
    (* full_case, parallel_case *)  
    case({rst, clear})  
        2'b00: begin 
                q <= d; 
                qn<=~d;
               end
        default: begin     
                    q <= 1'b0;  
                    qn <=1'b1;
                end 
    endcase
    end                     
endmodule
```

But I get the following error:

```
The statements in this 'always' block are outside the scope of the synthesis policy. Only an 'if' statement is allowed at the top level in this always block. (ELAB-302)
*** Presto compilation terminated with 1 errors. ***
```

I also tried with

```
if(~rst & ~clear)
```

but I have errors too.

Do you have an idea to correct my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to write a async reset, set (clear) flip-flop in Verilog RTL is:

```
always @(posedge clk or posedge rst or posedge clear) begin
  if (rst) begin
    // Aysnc Reset
    q <= 'b0 ;
  end
  else if (clear) begin
    // Async Clear 
    q <= 'b0 ;
  end
  else begin
    // Sync logic here
    q <= d;
  end
end

assign qn = ~n;
```

The little trick for `qn` requires it to be a `wire`, currently defined as a `reg`. `reg q,qn;` should just be `reg q;`

Also for cleaner code a new header type is cleaner and avoids repetition:

```
module dff_2rst(
    input      clk,
    input      d,
    input      rst,
    input      clear,
    output reg q,
    output     qn );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Morgan. Your code was inspiring to me. I couldn't use

```
assign qn=~q;
```

Because I got the error:

```
qn is not a valid left-hand side of a continuous assignment.
```

But I modified your code in the following manner and it works:

```
module dff_2rst(q,qn,clk,d, rst,clear);
    input  clk,d, rst, clear ;
    output q,qn;
    reg q,qn;
    always @(posedge clk or posedge rst or posedge clear)    //asynchronous reset    
//
    begin
        if (rst) begin
         // Aysnc Reset
            q <= 'b0 ; 
            qn<= 'b1 ;   
        end
        else if (clear) begin
        // Async Clear 
            q <= 'b0 ;
            qn<= 'b1 ;
        end
        else begin
        // Sync logic here
            q <= d;
            qn<= ~d;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: Do not define as reg, leave as a wire.

Comment: `reg q,qn;` should just be `reg q;`

Comment: I tried, but I got the error `Assigment to 'qn' requires that it be a register. (VER-952)`

Comment: @Morgan, I got it: I use only `reg q;` if I use your code with `assign`. May I ask you why is it better than my version?

Comment: Simply less lines of code implies easier maintenance, less bugs. With a simple invert it protects you from making a typo in one of the three cases.